# EditText.getText has a delay

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I have this code:

```
void sendMessage(){
    EditText messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String messageString = messageText.getText().toString();
    LinearLayout chatLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatView);
    TextView chatMessage = new TextView(this);
    chatMessage.setText(messageString);
    chatLayout.addView(chatMessage);
    messageText.setText("");
    scrollChatDown();
    /*
    int arraySize = messages.size();
    messages.set(arraySize + 1, chatMessage);
    */
}
```

When I call the function sendMessage(); by a button, it gives an empty TextView, when I call the function again, it gives me a TextView with the text.

**Output**

[image]

I did what jiotman said but it didn't work, now I have this

```
void sendMessage(){
    TextView chatMessage = new TextView(this);
    EditText messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String messageString = messageText.getText().toString();
    LinearLayout chatLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatView);
    chatLayout.addView(chatMessage);
    chatMessage.setText(messageString);
    messageText.setText("");
    scrollChatDown();
    /*
    int arraySize = messages.size();
    messages.set(arraySize + 1, chatMessage);
    */
}
```

Comment: post a little bit more code about it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you`r trying to implement kind of list with item population.

I`d use bubble list view for this purpose, here is a simple tutorials how to do it.

http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-bubble/

http://blog.booleanbites.com/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html

Comment: Yeah, but I would like it to do it with TextViews

Comment: Okay, then try to move view finding out of the sendMessage method. You should call findViewById for EditText and LinearLayout in onCreate() method.